# Lotus Notes - Compressed File Database

Tags: database, compression, lotus-notes, attachment, lotusscript

I'm enhancing a Lotus Notes application database (mainApp) that involves file attachments stored in a different database (data repository DB). The current implementation is that there is a main dataRepDB in a main server, then it has replica on many local servers. When users attached file in mainApp, it is actually attached to a document in the local dataRepDB. Then the local dataRepDB replicates to the main. The recurring problem is that documents in mainApp is not processed as long as the related dataRepDB documents are not complete. Sometimes, the replcation fails so the mainApp documents are stuck. My proposal was to use file compression to the attachments so that it can be uploaded faster to the main dataRepDB, without using any replica. Can you give me some tips on how I can do this? I will be using java for the file compression (the code is ready), my problem is how I will implement the process (flow).

Comment: Have you tried the "Use LZ1 compression for attachments" database property to reduce size/replication time?

Comment: That's a good idea @Rob, but I'm thinking what are the things that I should consider if I use it (aside from the client and server versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Use LZ1 compression for attachments" database property is worth trying prior to modifying your existing process. Considerations include:

1) You should be using Domino 6 or higher with your database format at [ODS 43 or higher](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/use-lz1-compression-for-attachments).

2) If users are uploading files from a web browser instead of the Notes client, the "File compression on upload" server setting [must be enabled](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21090049).

3) After enabling the property, existing attachments are not automatically compressed. You must execute a compact -ZU on the database to [apply LZ1 compression](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/categories/notes-domino/39-huffmanntolz1.html). (Some versions of Domino have issues with this command for large databases, but [there is a workaround](http://www.leadershipbynumbers.com/ms.nsf/d6plinks/BMAA-7C9KES).)